# SQL Server 2008 - Use IDENTITY field when inserting a row

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

My table has 3 columns `ID`, `ISOCode` and `CountryName`.

Column `ID` is an IDENTITY column.

When I insert new records into this table, I want to populate the `ISOCode` field - on occasion - with the same value as the `ID` field.

I've tried SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @@IDENTITY and IDENT_CURRENT but none of these seems to work.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could write a trigger to update the ISOCode column

In Trigger use the code below

```
update T set T.ISOCode=I.ID
from your_table T
join INSERTED I
on T.ID=I.ID
```